# Indexes of widgets instances starts with '2' in 'wp_options' table

Tags: widgets, dashboard, options

I have interesting question about widget instances saved in `wp_options` table. I have spent pretty much time until I figured it out but still don't know why is it happening.
**Problem:**
So the problem is that when I drag any widget and drop it on any sidebar in my Admin Dashboard its ID starts with 2. For example when I drop Text widget its ID is `widget_text-2` despite of fact that it's first widget. What's more interesting, when I go to `wp_options` table and unserialize serialized data from `widget_text` option, what I get is array with indexes starting from **2**. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **why** part can be found in ticket [#24889](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24889).

Let me [quote](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/timeline?from=2015-03-07T16%3A28%3A14Z&precision=second) @azaozz:

> When support for multi-use widgets was introduced, a lot of widgets
>   got converted from "single" to "multi" at the same time. To keep
>   backward compatibility and not break the existing widgets, there was
>   some conversion code that would set the "single" widgets instances to
>   `*-1` (not sure why not `*-0`, it was a long time ago). In order to not overwrite the converted data, the new multi-widgets instances had to
>   start form `2`. As @tyxla mentions, this doesn't break anything and if
>   changed to `-0` or `-1`, in theory can still overwrite someone's single
>   widgets.

The available *Text* widget is listed in the global `$wp_registered_widgets` as:

```
[text-1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Text
        [id] => text-1
        [callback] => Array
            (
                [0] => WP_Widget_Text Object
                    (
                        [id_base] => text
                        [name] => Text
                        [option_name] => widget_text
                        [alt_option_name] => 
                        [widget_options] => Array
                            (
                                [classname] => widget_text
                                [customize_selective_refresh] => 1
                                [description] => Arbitrary text or HTML.
                            )

                        [control_options] => Array
                            (
                                [id_base] => text
                                [width] => 400
                                [height] => 350
                            )

                        [number] => 1
                        [id] => text-1
                        [updated] => 
                    )

                [1] => display_callback
            )

        [params] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [number] => -1
                    )

            )

        [classname] => widget_text
        [customize_selective_refresh] => 1
        [description] => Arbitrary text or HTML.
    )
```

I think the 1, in the `text-1` id, comes from this part of the [`WP_Widget::_register()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/df256f9feee6664dbdae38010132439bf6239f63/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php#L269):

```
if ( $empty ) {
    // If there are none, we register the widget's existence with a generic template.
    $this->_set( 1 );
    $this->_register_one();
}
```

When the available multi widgets are listed with `wp_list_widgets(),` the  [`next_widget_id_number()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_widget_id_number/) function is used to calculate the *next widget id number*. It's defined as:

```
function next_widget_id_number( $id_base ) {
    global $wp_registered_widgets;
    $number = 1;

    foreach ( $wp_registered_widgets as $widget_id => $widget ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/' . $id_base . '-([0-9]+)$/', $widget_id, $matches ) )
            $number = max($number, $matches[1]);
    }
    $number++;

    return $number;
}
```

For the `text-1` id, the next widget id number is `max( 1, 1 ) + 1 = 2`.

So when we drag the first multi *Text* widget over an available sidebar, the `widget_text` option is stored as (adjusted for better readability):

```
a:2:{
i:2;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:0:"";s:6:"filter";b:0;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;
}
```

where we notice the `i:2` part and the `sidebars_widgets` option will contain the `text_2` instance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It explains a lot. I spent a lot of time trying to figure it out but couldn't find why it's 2. I expected 0 or 1 but definetly not 2. Now I see why it happens. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it helped. I agree that it's not easy to dig through the core code to get an overview of how the widget system works. I think I only scratched the surface here ;-) @SebastianKaczmarek